# Limit Continuity

Tags: limits, continuity

> 3. What value of $k$ makes the function below continuous?
>
> $$a)\qquad f(x)~=~\begin{cases} x^2+3 &:& x\leq 1\\[1ex] 5x+k &:& x>1\end{cases}$$

this is the problem I am stuck and have no idea how to start

Comment: Okay, and what's your question?

Comment: Do you know the definition of continuity in the context of limits?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know where to start, simplify the problem and see if you can solve the simpler version. Often you will then understand how to tackle the full problem.

In this case, pick a random value for $k$. Maybe $k=0$ or $k=42$. It doesn't matter what you pick; just make it concrete. Now, decide whether $f$ is continuous.

How did you make the decision? Can you do it again, but keeping $k$ as an unknown variable?

Comment: This is a good hint, *assuming* that the OP knows how to do the simpler version.

Comment: @projectilemotion I see what you mean, but even if they can't, at least the attempt is better than staring blankly at the problem.

Comment: Indeed, I agree. (+1) The OP can easily look up on Google how to do it anyway: "How to determine if a piecewise function is continuous"